# not enough memory to run excel 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, excel-2013, npoi

I have a MVC application that uses NPOI version:2.1.3.0 to read and write in excel file and user can download that excel file in their local machine. File format: xlsx.

```
public ActionResult NPOI()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(@"\Content\SampleExcel.xlsx"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        XSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
        ISheet sheet = (ISheet)templateWorkbook.GetSheet("Sheet1");
        IRow dataRow = (IRow)sheet.GetRow(1);
        dataRow.GetCell(0).SetCellValue(77);
        sheet.ForceFormulaRecalculation = true;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        templateWorkbook.Write(ms);
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "SampleExcel.xlsx");
    }
```

Writing in excel file is working fine. But when browser is IE and excel 2013 in user machine.

If after downloads completes user uses IE open(preview file) option is selected:
[image: IE Open option]

Then in excel 2013 this error is observed:
[image: Excel error 1]

Followed by:

[image: Excel error 2]

Although the template file(SampleExcel.xlsx) which is there on server side is open and saved with excel 2013. Then also I don't know why it is showing file is corrupt. And there is enough memory on user's machine, it never touches it's peak value in task manager.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Windows/IE is being used? Is it running with reduced privileges? What about if you save an excel file created in excel to the server and open it using the machine. Does that work? Fundamentally, there's either a problem in the way the file is generated/served or in the machine downloading/opening it. We need to narrow down which it is. Oh and check the event log (System/Application) on the machine after it fails to load. See if there's any related entries

Comment: Windows:Windows 7 Enterprise Service pack 1(64 bit); IE: 11. Admin privilege. If i save the excel file and open it excel 2013 then its work fine. And in Event viewer :  "The description for Event ID 0 from source MSOIDSVC.EXE cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event."

Comment: You can explore this technique to generate an Excel sheet via code without using any components - http://mvark.blogspot.in/2010/04/export-to-excel-without-using.html

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, instead of downloading and opening outside of IE, can you try opening an excel file inside of IE that doesn't come from your generator? Eg link to one created by Excel/similar. I'm trying to narrow down if it's IE being unable to open any excel files or the file you generate being fine except for IE.

Comment: Thanks Basic, if I open excel file with IE, it works fine. And as per System/Application event log, I just repaired excel 2013, problem still persist.

Comment: Hi Mvark, I need to migrate old project that uses NPOI dll to new one. I think if I change the architecture by not using that, that will big effort for me as if now, because of time constraint.

Comment: Hi, I have narrowed down the problem, it seems that IE 11 temporary internet folders has some rights or folder size problem. let me look more closely. however if anyone faced this issue let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, actually the problem is not with the memory, but with the user permission on that particular machine. If Admin guys try to do same above mentioned steps with no customization in access then no problem is faced by him.

Anyhow thanks everyone for your time:)